# Comparing 2 text files

Tags: c++

I've been writing a code, and I have an issue.

I have 2 text files .txt, which look like that :

File no. 1  (fasta)

```
DOJHLOP01DWJWJ 
TCGATTCTATGGAGGGATGCTGGCAAGGCTCCGGAAGCAGCATCAGCAATTAAAAAAT
DOJHLOP01C1GFF 
TTTACACAGTTGCAAGCCCTGAAGCTTGTGCTTCGATTCTATGGAGGGATGCTGGCAA
DOJHLOP01CAI84 
AGGCGTCGCAGACAGGTTACTTATGTTTGAACATAGTGTTTACACAGTTGCAAGCCCT
```

File no. 2 (qual)

```
DOJHLOP01DWJWJ 
32 31 29 26 30 27 32 32 31 30 28 26 26 28 27 19 26 31 24 32 31 30 25 25 29 
DOJHLOP01C1GFF
28 28 16 26 31 32 31 28 32 31 27 30 31 29 23 32 29 28 16 31 31 29 24 32 31 
DOJHLOP01CAI84 
31 30 25 30 27 24 31 31 31 32 32 31 30 24 27 21 31 27 32 31 30 25 25 28 31
```

As ypu can see, every 2nd line is the same, and as a result of I want to get the output file, that contains the equivalent lines, which are different, i.ex.

```
TCGATTCTATGGAGGGATGCTGGCAAGGCTCCGGAAGCAGCATCAGCAATTAAAAAAT
32 31 29 26 30 27 32 32 31 30 28 26 26 28 27 19 26 31 24 32 31 30 25 25 29
```

I've written the code, using vector, but something is wrong, because I get a blank file as the output. 
Please, help me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string fasta,qual;
        vector <string> v1,v2;
        ifstream file;
        fstream out_file;
        int i;

        cout <<"insert the name of fasta file"<<endl;
        cin>>fasta;
        cout<<"instert the name of qual file"<<endl;
        cin>>qual;

        file.open(fasta.c_str(),ifstream::in);
        while(getline(file,fasta))
        {
            v1.push_back(fasta);
        }
        file.close();

        file.open(qual.c_str(),ifstream::in);
        while(getline(file,qual))
        {
            v2.push_back(qual);
        }
        file.close();

        out_file.open ("out_file.txt");

        for(i=0;i<v1.size();i++) //assuming the qual and fasta have the same numer of lines
        {
                if(v1[i]!=v2[i]) //if two lines are different
                {
                        out_file<<v1[i]; //write this line into the out_file
                        out_file<<'\n';
                        out_file<<v2[i]; //write this line into the out_file
                        out_file<<'\n';
                }

        }

        out_file.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Is that the real code ? The `plik3.close();` seems confusing.

Comment: I assumke the plik2.close is him failign to completely clean his example for us. I ignored it.

Comment: Well I don't see anything obviously wrong here, so maybe something important got stripped down or lost in translation (`plik` is `file` in polish) for the sake of the example. And if one ignores it, the file might be empty, because `out_file` did not manage to close at the time of checking. It is important to prepare a "working" fail-example.

Comment: I'm sorry for that mistake, I'm Polish, and I've translated parts of my code to English to make it more understandable. Plik3 is out_file and it is correctly closed in my original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `fstream out_file;`
to `ofstream out_file;`

Comment: Ummm [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) says `explicit basic_fstream( const char* filename,                                 
               ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out );` so either you or they are wrong.

Comment: hmm, mine wont create the file if fstream mode is ios_base::in|ios_base::out, but right now I am shaky on why. Certainly it creates teh file if needed with ofstream.

Comment: I checked it too. Well i'm puzzled but it seems, that in `in | out` it does not create the file. Also I experience a different behaviour than OP, 'cause he/she says that she gets blank file. I get no file, but when I create it by hand, it gets filled properly o_O.

Comment: When I test it, if the file does not exist, it's created properly.